# how to convert LMDB data format in NVIDIA DIGITS to CSV to use in Torch?

Tags: caffe, torch, nvidia-digits

I want to use Torch for training. I have my image data in LMDB format and I have done the conversion using NVIDIA DIGITS (caffe).
How can I convert this .lmdb format to csv or .t7 so that I can use it in Torch?

Comment: why not using the text file used to generate the lmdb?

Comment: firstly, I used text files to get .lmdb data. and I have uploaded them to NVIDIA DIGITS and have these files (train.lmdb and test.lmdb).

Comment: how different are these files from csv files required by torch?